# Using layout with knitr

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I want to make a single figure in R with two plots in a markdown file with `knitr`.  Normally, this is easy to do with `layout(t(1:2))` or `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`.  Can I do this with `knitr`, or will it always make two separate figures?

Here is a minimum working example which creates a file called `./junk.Rmd` and `./junk.md` in your working directory along with two files `./figure/junkislands1.png` (which only includes the first plot) and `./figure/junkislands2.png` (which includes both plots that I want).

````
require(knitr)
temp <- "```{r junkislands, fig.width=8, fig.height=5}
layout(t(1:2))
pie(islands)
barplot(islands)
```"
cat(temp, file="junk.Rmd")
knit("junk.Rmd", "junk.md")
````

The problem isn't so much that it creates two .png files, but rather that the markdown file `junk.md` includes both of them.

When I make that markdown into html, it includes both .png files when I only want the one with both figures plotted.

Here is the file `junk.md` that is generated from knitr:

````
```r
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
pie(islands)
```

![plot of chunk junkislands](figure/junkislands1.png) 

```r
barplot(islands)
```

![plot of chunk junkislands](figure/junkislands2.png)
````

Comment: strictly speaking, this is a bug of `knitr` (https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/292); I will try to fix it later; thanks

Comment: I have [fixed](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/3508ddb86f0068c17570b3c71dc1e79414041627) this bug in the development version: https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme You can certainly use `fig.keep='last'`, but that will not be required any more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at http://yihui.name/knitr/options and specifically `fig.keep`. I think you want `fig.keep = 'last'`

````
require(knitr)
temp <- "```{r junkislands, fig.width=8, fig.height=5, fig.keep = 'last'}
layout(t(1:2))
pie(islands)
barplot(islands)
```"
cat(temp, file="junk.Rmd")
knit("junk.Rmd", "junk.md")
````

gives

````
```r
layout(t(1:2))
pie(islands)
barplot(islands)
```

![plot of chunk junkislands](figure/junkislands.png)
````

Comment: just a side note -- you can call `knit(text = temp)` directly instead of writing the text to `junk.Rmd`.